# Get the column name based on it's value in row in SQL

Tags: sql

My table looks like this:

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3
A   0   1   0
B   1   0   1
C   1   0   1
```

I want the name of the columns where value is 1 , the results should look like this:

```
ID  ColName     
A   Col2        
B   Col1,Col3       
C   Col1,Col2
```

Please advice on how can I get the results.
Thanks!

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by concatenating together the values.  Here is one method:

```
select id,
       concat( (case when col1 = 1 then 'col1;' else ''),
               (case when col2 = 1 then 'col2;' else ''),
               (case when col3 = 1 then 'col3;' else '')
             )
from t;
```

This is generic SQL (well, actually ANSI standard).  The specifics might very by database, but this should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

In case of **`ORACLE`** database,

```
SELECT ID
  , RTRIM (
    DECODE(COL1, 1, 'COL1, ', '') 
      || DECODE(COL2, 1, 'COL2, ', '')  
      || DECODE(COL3, 1, 'COL3 ', '')
    , ',')AS ColName
FROM MY_TABLE
```